# How to create a child document from a parent doc - IBM Domino Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotus-formula

I would like to create a child document from a parent doc. For example when I click an action button I would like it to create a child document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your response document form to the type "Response" or "Response-to-response". Then set your action's formula to

```
@Command([Compose]; ""; "Your Form Name");
```

[More information here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/cd8c760c4c0ee45f85256c54004b6b0a?OpenDocument)

Comment: is there a way to then make this new child document available in a view?

Comment: Set your view's formula to: SELECT Form = "Your Form Name" | @IsResponseDoc

Comment: Thanks, does my child doc need to be response or respone-to-response?

Comment: That works, now I have a Dialog List Field, so when I select more than one item in the parent doc, I would like it to create a child doc for each item selected (All using the same child form). So if 3 items are selected in the field, I would like it to create 3 child docs using the same form but with different titles

Comment: Ask that as another question. But more importantly: go find some books or on-line classes to cover basic Lotus Notes development topics! For the level of questions that you are asking, even one of the very old ones will be fine - and they won't cost you much.